# Logging "bounce" - Analytics

Tags: php, seo, google-analytics

I'm not quite sure if my title's a good one but anyways. Onwards to my issue/question.

I'm working on developing my firms new newsletter, which is intended to not only provide our customers with nice deals and fun info, but it's also going to be used by us inorder to determine what our customers want.

Now my problem arise when I decided to add a "inhouse" logging, that by itself is by no means complicated. The URLs in the newsletter follow a structure as follows; http://domain.com/?page=newsclick&n_ref=RANDOM_CODE, the code is saved and all is well, the RANDOM_CODE is just a value saved upon creating a link so each link to a destination, this is where my problem is. If I bounce them via my own logging.php file, does googleanalytics follow? Because in logging.php there's nothing printed as it's just to bounce the visitor to the correct page.

I wonder, should I do it all diffrently, or is google intelligent enough to catch this "problem" and overlook it? I'm quite the novice with Analytics, as I'm pretty sure you can see.

Grateful for any and all help!

Kind regards, Johan.

Comment: if you have no google-analytics code in logging.php then it (google-analytics) wont be logging anything

Comment: I'm not sure if I expressed myself poorly or not, in anycase I will try to clarify a bit.

What I want to do, is to track the clicks with both analytics and my own system, my "trouble area" so to speak, is that logging.php, and I wonder if I somehow can get around the problem of analytics being unable to understand where the click comes from when landing on the normal website.

Comment: i think this should answer it: https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1136920&topic=1136919&ctx=topic

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much for your help that does indeed look to be spot on what I need! :)